# Converting multiple python scripts to executable format

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains 3 python scripts depended to each other and also the folder contains the input files that I will pass to these scripts.

Now I want to convert my scripts from `.py` to `.exe` format.

I am aware of the package called `pyinstaller` that will convert my python scripts to .exe format.

But when I am converting my .py file to .exe using the below code :

`pyinstaller --onefile Script1.py`

The above command ran successfully.It creates two folder `build` and`dist`, but I could not see any `Script1.exe` file in my dist folder.

Also how to convert the scripts to `.exe` if my python scripts are dependent to each other.

Comment: PyInstaller finds all the import statements in your script. It finds the imported modules and looks in them for import statements, and so on recursively, until it has a complete list of modules your script may use.

Comment: @filipe- But what could be the reason ,that my .exe file is not getting generated in the `dist` folder?

Comment: You can try to use the --log-level debug and -d flags to find out if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the scripts are in the same root folder like this?

```
|- script1.py
|- script2.py
|- script3.py
```

I'm also assuming that script1.py is calling your following scripts, something like this?

./script1.py

```py
from script2 import function2
from script3 import function3

def function1(*args):
    "do something with function2 and function3 here"
    data = import_data()
    new_data = function2(data)
    newer_data = function3(new_data)
```

you could move your scripts to be part of a package, and then write a new wrapper around it.
the tree structure would now look like this.

```
|- script_run.py
|- myscripts
   |- __init__.py # empty file that tells python this is a python package
   |- script1.py
   |- script2.py
   |- script3.py
```

script_run.py

```py
from myscripts.script1 import function1

function1()  # add whatever arguments are needed here.
```

I'm not sure of the finer details of how `pyinstaller` works, as it has been a very long time, but I would assume that it would be able to figure out that the directory is a package and build your exe as such.

*note: you may need to tweak your import statements to use `.script2` to let the scripts in the `myscripts` folder know that they should be using the `script2.py` file located in the same package.*